# How do I select elements from one specific class?

Tags: jquery, css

How do I select the **bed-row-count** span elements only for **beds-21** here? Such that I can use jQuery **each** to iterate over them...

e.g.

```
jQuery('selector').each(function(index) {
    ...do something to each span...
});
```

Here's example HTML...

```
<table>
    <tr class="beds-20">
        <td>...</td>
        <td><img /></td>
        <td><span class="bed-row-count">1</span> ...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="beds-20">
        <td>...</td>
        <td><img /></td>
        <td><span class="bed-row-count">2</span> ...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr class="beds-21">
        <td>...</td>
        <td><img /></td>
        <td><span class="bed-row-count">1</span> ...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="beds-21">
        <td>...</td>
        <td><img /></td>
        <td><span class="bed-row-count">2</span> ...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: No, Each loop needed Only this one line is your solution check it out the snippet:
$('[class*="bed-row-count"]').parent().parent('tr.beds-21').css('background', 'fireBrick')
Don't forget to upvote me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [.find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) function to search for span and do something to it on `beds-21` class.

Run snippet below.

```js
$('.beds-21').each(function(index) {
  var mySpan = $(this).find('span')

  //Display the text of each span
  console.log(mySpan.text())
  
  //Display the actual element
  console.log(mySpan[0].outerHTML)

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="beds-20">
    <td>...</td>
    <td><img /></td>
    <td><span class="bed-row-count">1</span> ...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="beds-20">
    <td>...</td>
    <td><img /></td>
    <td><span class="bed-row-count">2</span> ...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr class="beds-21">
    <td>...</td>
    <td><img /></td>
    <td><span class="bed-row-count">1</span>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="beds-21">
    <td>...</td>
    <td><img /></td>
    <td><span class="bed-row-count">2</span> ...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
jQuery('table tr.beds-21 td span.bed-row-count').each(function(index) {
        ...do something to each span...
});
```

Comment: Thanks Steven2105. Yes you'd think so wouldn't you! I've tried all manner of combinations like that and it doesn't. I'm confused and frustrated; hence the query here...

Comment: Well, this works (you could also use .beds-21 .bed-row-count since it's more logic). If you color the selected elements by that query, you can see, that only the ones with bed-21 are selected. If you replace the bed-21 to bed-22 it only selects that as well. Or did you mean something different?

Answer (score 0):

**Only this one line is your solution:**

`$('[class*="bed-row-count"]').parent().parent('tr.beds-21').css('background', 'fireBrick')`

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr class="beds-20">
        <td>fgfggfg</td>
        <td><img /></td>
        <td><span class="bed-row-count">1</span> gfgfgf</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="beds-20">
        <td>nmhhjh</td>
        <td><img /></td>
        <td><span class="bed-row-count">2</span> rergg</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr class="beds-21">
        <td>ghjhkj</td>
        <td><img /></td>
        <td><span class="bed-row-count">1</span> 2ddfd</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="beds-21">
        <td>ghgjhg</td>
        <td><img /></td>
        <td><span class="bed-row-count">2</span>12323</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>

$('[class*="bed-row-count"]').parent().parent('tr.beds-21').css('background', 'fireBrick')
</script>
```